# Using node js to get query parameters from an url

Tags: node.js

This is how part of my server side node js script looks:

```
var url = require('url');
var https= require('https');
var onset = function(request,response){
var name = url.parse(request.url,true).query.a;
var fame = url.parse(request.url,true).query.b;
}
https.createServer(options,onset).listen(8888);
```

while this is my request url:

```
https://10.10.10.188:8888/forecast/autoip.json?a=hello&b=bello
```

but only variable name takes the value "hello"
while variable fame shows that it is undefined.

Any help?

Comment: Everything is ok. Once check the `var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
  console.log(queryObject); `

Comment: It shows {a:'hello'}
Not showing anything related to variable b

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you're copying and pasting that exact URL? Also, you're using different ports. Is that a typo or are you hitting the wrong server?

Comment: Different ports was just a typo.Question edited.
Doing everything the same way but not working.Tried Again.